# Can't list files when accessing FTP folder from Heroku app

Tags: java, heroku, ftp

I'm have created a java app that reads files from a FTP server.I have tested this app locally(with success) and now i have deployed this app to heroku.
This is a piece a my code :

```
public void CSVListing() {
    String[] fnames = {"1","2","3","4"};
    try {
        try {
            client.connect(host);
        } catch (SocketException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        //----------------------------------------
        boolean login = false;
        try {
            login = client.login(user, pass);
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (login) {
            System.out.println("Login success...");
            //boolean logout = false;
            System.out.println("ready to work");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Login fail...");
        }
        //----------------------------------------
        System.out.println(client.printWorkingDirectory());
        fnames = client.listNames();
        System.out.println("FNAMES ARE" + fnames);
        for(String s: fnames){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

......................................................

I have locally executed this code and it gives me a list of the files, but when I execute this on my heroku app online >>fnames = client.listNames();<< returns null according to my logs. I'm accessing the same FTP host in both executions (locally and online).
Can somebody help me and tell me where i'm wrong?

Comment: You should check that you have permission to list the files in this directory. Also note that an FTP server may put you on a different directory initially than what you would expect and may also hide part of the file system from you and only show you a sub-tree of folders.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your permissions? Awhile ago I pass through something similar, the problem was that the user connecting to the FTP server didn't have permission to download files.

Comment: The FTP server is a free FTP server online.
Im loging in from the same user(which is admin), both when i run the app from my PC and when i try to run it from Heroku. In the first case it works, so i guess the user does have permission to do so.

Comment: Is it possible that the FTP server is blocking requests from Heroku?